# Can't scroll through the starred messages in the chatrooms

Tags: bug, chat, design, chat-stars

When I hit on the `show 9 more` (or with whatever number), the container expands but goes behind the footer.

Here's a snapshot (from the JavaScript room):

[image]

This screenshot is taken on a 1440x900 resolution screen. As you can see, the scrollbar is way off.

(It seems more of a CSS issue to me.)